# How do I implement "if exists update" with custom migration in EF Core?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to create a migration for a new entity. Here is the thing, though: due to it being saved as an inner object for a different entity, I have no way to check if it exists (If it is, it needs to be updated).

Now, what I would like to have, is the ability to annotate the table (more specifically, the PK) so that if I try to add an entity that already exists, it will update it, instead of fail.

Is this possible? If so, how?

(here is a sample code that shows the issue).

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(@"Host=localhost;Database=mydatabase3;Username=postgres;Password=1234");
    }
}


public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public Blog ContainerBlog { get; set; }
    public int blabla { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Blog b1 = new Blog();
        Blog b2 = new Blog();
        b2.ContainerBlog = b1;
        using (var ctx = new BloggingContext())
        {
            ctx.Database.Migrate();

            ctx.Blogs.Add(b1);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
        using (var ctx = new BloggingContext())
        {
            ctx.Blogs.Add(b2);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't want to (and can't) confuse Add and Update this way. There are other solutions, but post (an outline of) your datamodel first. Including the DbSets in the DbContext .

Comment: Added example (this is not my actual datamodel, but it shows the problem)

Comment: Seeing as B1, b2 are still only blogs couldnt you just query your database to get back a blog matching B2 and if you do then update that model, otherwise add a new one?

Comment: b2 does not exist. It refers to b1.

The problem is that I cannot add b2, because it automatically tries to also add (again) b1.
Now, in theory I could just check if b2 has a reference to b1, and if so attach it, however, note that this could create a long chain(b50->b49->b48....), which makes it much more difficult to have this test.